# Printing newline in richtextbox in c# using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox, rtf

I am making a Windows form application in C# using Visual Studio 2012. I have a string with "|". I want to put a "newline" where there is "|".

My approach is below. But it is printing "This\nis\nmy\nprogram" in the richtextbox.

```
// richtextbox1 in the instace I have made with Richtextbox and it is working correctely.

String myString="This|is|my|program";
String relpacedString=myString.Replace("|","\n");
richtextbox1.append(replacedString);

//this is printing "This\nis\nmy\nprogram" in the textbox
```

How can I fix this issue ?"

Answer (score 3):

Try using `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`.

Better yet, use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to insert the correct carriage return character(s):

```
String replacedString = myString.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
```

This way, you're not guessing what the correct newline string is. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx):

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Comment: I made another project and test this. It worked. But in the project I am working this isn't working. MultiLine is TRUE in both cases. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure richtextbox1.MultiLine is set to true.

Comment: I made another project and test this. It worked. But in the project I am working this isn't working. MultiLine is TRUE in both cases. Could you help me ?